# Nested conditional

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to assign a value to a variable depending on the viewport size using Hooks in Gatsby
I'm using nested conditionals and it works when I test the webpage for the first time but if I resize manually the window browser it displays the following error:

> Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement

As the react Docs says: Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. So I tried using a ternary operation:

```
let filter = (useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 695px)' })) ? 2 : (useMediaQuery({ query: '(min-width: 900px)' })) ? 4 : 3
```

I also tried with:

```
if (useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 695px)' })) 
 { filter = 2 } else if (useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 900px)' })) 
 { filter = 4 } else { filter = 3 }
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Yes, don't put hooks inside an if..

Answer (score 1):

According to the rules of hooks, all hooks should be called at the top level of a component.

```
export function YourComponent() {
  const isSmallFormFactor = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 695px)' });
  const isMediumFormFactor = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 900px)' });

  const filter = isSmallFormFactor
    ? 2
    : isMediumFormFactor
    ? 4
    : 3;

  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```